# App apk level change in google play console

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I have upload an application on play store it is published. When i try to install on my device it show compatible error for my device. When i check the api level is 16-19 in console but when i check my gradle file it show my min apk level 16 ,    compileSdkVersion 29 and  targetSdkVersion 29.[Image From Android Studio Gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWiIr.png)

[Image From GooglePlay Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbjnv.png)

Comment: How do you install on your device? Studio? adb CLI? Play Store? Other? What's the exact error message? If adb, can you show the error message in the logcat?

Comment: i didn't install it yet it shows your device is not compatible on play store. On my android studio sdk version is ok as i attached the picture of it. But on the developer console it shows apk level 16-19 target sdk 29

Comment: It looks like you have maxSdkVersion set to 19. Maybe it's set directly in your AndroidManifest.xml instead of your gradle build file?